# How to code drag an object using a mouse in 3D space

Tags: opengl

I am using OpenGL to drag a 3D object in 3D space.
Since I am totally new in OpenGL, I do not understand what other people said about mouse dragging. In fact I need a sample code + explanation, just explanation is not enough for me(unless it is simple and detailed enough). 
I read other forums too, but I still do not understand.

Such as these forums, I do not understand at all...

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=53232
http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=296160

My problem is How to do as written??

Answer (score 0):

Mouse movement is in screen coordinates (2D) while object movement is in world space (3D). Therefore you need to restrict the object movement to a line or plane before translating those coordinates.

After you set your movement plane, translating screen coordinates to world coordinates is as simple as casting a ray into the scene, intersecting it with the movement plane.

So it's a two step process. Those links you posted provide more detail. If that is not enough, please show us what you've got and where you got stuck.

Comment: How do you restrict the object movement?
And how do you intersect world coordinates with movement plane?
I know how to set screen coor -to world coor.
Actually I have not started, because I do not know how to start...
I just finished drawing objects.

Comment: void mouseDrag(int x, int y)
{int button;
int state;
GLfloat translateX;
GLfloat translateY;
if ((state == GLUT_DOWN) && (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)) // translate
{translateX += (400-x)/ 1000.0f;
translateY += (400-y) / 1000.0f;}
gl_draw(translateX, translateY);
glutPostRedisplay();}
in gl_draw() i use glTranslatef(translateX,translateY, -6.0f); to translate the object.
and in main(), glutMotionFunc(mouseDrag);

Comment: But I keep getting this error : Error 2 error C2664: 'glutMotionFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int,int)' F:\UTM courses\OpenGL Tutorials\VidTut\cube\main.cpp 475, I think it refers to the mouseDrag() function. But where is the error